# Aggregate & Total in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Data:

```
ProjectA,12
ProjectB,24
ProjectA,15
```

I'd like to calculate the sum for every project and then total so that the result is:

```
Project    Sum
ProjectA    27
ProjectB    24
Total       51
```

Is there a function that can do this? Right now I need to do 2 calls:

```
paste('Size of all projects: ', sum(projects$size))
aggregate(projects$size, by=list(projects$name), sum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found a useful function for that: addmargins().

```
myData <- data.frame(projects=c("projectA","projectB","projectA"), value=c(5,10,15))
myData
  projects value
1 projectA     5
2 projectB    10
3 projectA    15

addmargins(with(myData, tapply(value, projects, sum)))
projectA projectB      Sum 
      20       10       30
```

Grouping can be done in many ways. Since in this case it's a vector - I use tapply.